# Ajax POST is not posting onclick to current page

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Alright so this has been bugging me for a long time now... I have tried everything but I cant get it to work!

So what I want to have is a link that acts as a button, and once you click it, it POSTs an ID number of the button in the form "{ 'id' : id }"

**edit-homepage.php:**

```
<script>
$(function() { // document ready
   $('a.inactive').on('click', function(event) {
     event.preventDefault(); // instad of return false

     var id = $(this).data('id');

     // use $.post shorthand instead of $.ajax
     $.post('edit-homepage.php', {id: id}, function(response) {


       // after you get response from server
       editSlide(id);
     });

   });
 });
</script>
```

The a href button is created using PHP and I want it to call the ajax function postID( id ) which will post the id so that later I can populate a form via PHP using the posted id.

**edit-homepage.php:**

```
echo '<li><a class="inactive" id="slide-'.$info["id"].
'" onClick="postID('.$info["id"].'); editSlide('.$info["id"].'); return false;">'
.'<img src="../images/'.$info["img"].'" width="175"/><p>Edit Slide '
. $info["id"] .'</p></a></li>';
```

Currently, when I click the link, it opens the alert but it is EMPTY or Undefined. It is supposed to display "ID: 1" for example if the link clicked has a ID of 1.

**edit-homepage.php:**

```
    <script>
function editSlide($id) {
        <?PHP

        if (isset ($_POST['id'])) {
            echo "alert('success!2');";
        }$id = !empty($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : '';
        $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM slider WHERE id='$id'") or die(mysql_error()); 
        $info = mysql_fetch_array( $data );?>
        document.getElementById("edit-slide-id").innerHTML="Edit Slide #"+$id;
        document.getElementById("edit-form").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("short-title").value="<?PHP echo $info['s_title']; ?>";
}
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: can u check the view source for your link and see what u get for onClick="postID('.$info["id"].');

Comment: <a class="inactive" id="slide-1" onclick="postID(1); editSlide(1); return false;"><img src="../images/image-slider-1.jpg" width="175"><p>Edit Slide 1</p></a>

Comment: Is ID a php variable? Try `onClick="postID('<?php echo $info["id"]; ?>');`

Comment: the link turns out correctly. It is not my PHP fault. My link has onclick="postID(1);" which means that the PHP in my link is not the issue. Also, if I do alert("ID: " + id ); it will correctly print my ID,but when I try to do it with PHP $_POST['id']; it will not work, which is what i want it to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jquery, you don't need to use attributes to attach events, like that:

```
 $(function() { // document ready
   $('a.inactive').on('click', function(event) {
     event.preventDefault(); // instad of return false

     var id = $(this).data('id');

     // use $.post shorthand instead of $.ajax
     $.post('edit-homepage.php', {id: id}, function(response) {
       alert('ID:' + response);

       // after you get response from server
       editSlide(id);
     });

   });
 });
```

As of server side, try replacing raw

```
<?PHP echo $_POST['id']; ?>
```

With

```
<?php echo !empty($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : '' ?>
```

You likely get notice about `Undefined index id`, which breaks javascript if there is no `post` data.

**UPDATE**

edit-homepage.php shold be separated something like that:

```
if(!empty($_POST)) {
 // here you process your post data and return
 // only wenever you want to pass to script 
 // not all the html
} else {
 // here you output html and scripts, but don't do request processing
}
```

You should always remember, that your HTML rendering must always be separated from your logic. It is better to put `views` in separate files from logic, though it is not required, it is much easier to debug and maintain.

Comment: I like this approach, but its not working properly. For some reason the alert response is showing my entire webpage code... and when it passes the id to editslide(id) it passes 'undefined' so something is not right. What could be the problem?

Comment: @user3015190 The solution is to separate $_POST processing from webpage output, see update

Answer (score 0):

You can not include PHP code that is supposedly to run after the ajax call. The PHP code will be run only to generate the page. Anything you want to include in alert should be provided in the ajax response, in your case the data variable.

Comment: What I want to do is this. I have 4 buttons, with unique ID's, each button will display a form and populate the form with the ID specified. So even if what you say is true, if I type $_POST['id'] anywhere else in my page, it will not work and displays id as empty. which should have a value onclick.

Comment: So, are you posting the ajax call to the same page? Does that make sense? You should have another PHP page that handles the POST and returns a response in JSON, XML or whatever.

Comment: I dont know if it makes sense, but why is it so damn hard to pass a variable to PHP without refreshing the page!. I want to be able to click the link and pass the ID of the link to PHP to use and display a form and populate it from that ID. I do not want the page to refresh!

Comment: Why you need to call PHP code in the server for that? You already have the id in the javascript. If you want to post something to the server,  you are supposed to do something. Why you want to return the id that you post? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I need to pass the ID to PHP so I can query data from the database about that ID and return it to populate a form. All without refreshing the page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `alert('ID: ' + id)`.

The `$_POST['id']` part of the script does not react to the `AJAX` request. It is whatever the `$_POST['id']` value is when the script is output to the browser (i.e. when the page is first loaded).

You will see this if you view the source.

Comment: This is not what I want. I want to pass the ID to my PHP script, so that when someone clicks on the link it will display a form which requries this ID to populate it with data from a database.

Comment: Then why do you have `alert("ID: <?PHP echo $_POST['id']; ?>");` in the example and say "It is supposed to display "ID: 1" for example if the link clicked has a ID of 1."?

Comment: because, later on in my edit-homepage.php I have PHP which requires the ID to fetch data from a database and return the data to populate a form.

Answer (score 0):

```
alert ("ID:"+data);
```

then only you will get response

or

```
alert("ID"+id);
```

this will alert the id passes to function

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/U54ME/

```
$(".checkthisclass").click(function() {
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "edit-homepage.php",
      data: { 'id' : $(this).attr("slideid"); },      
      success: function(data) {
          alert(data);
      }
      });
} 
});
```

--

```
<ul>
<li><a class="inactive checkthisclass" id="slide-5" slideid = "5" ><img src="http://blog.entelo.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/stackoverflow-logo.png" width="175"/><p>Edit Slide 5</p></a></li>
</ul>
```